# defining a font within my dir does not work

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I'm trying to use `Lato` as my main font, but I would like to load it from my project folder. So I defined the following commands:

```
\newcommand*{\fontdir}[1][fonts/]{\def\@fontdir{#1}}
\fontdir

\newfontfamily\Lato[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=Lato-Regular.ttf,
  ItalicFont=Lato-Italic.ttf,
  BoldFont=Lato-Bold.ttf,
  BoldItalicFont=Lato-BoldItalic.ttf,
  NFSSFamily=latofont
]{Lato}
```

and set it as my main font

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{latofont}
```

but I get the following error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "latofont" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

I don't get it. Any help is appreciated.

## Update

I succeeded to load it by defining:

```
\newfontfamily\Lato[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  NFSSFamily=latofont
]{Lato-Regular.ttf}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Path=\@fontdir]{Lato-Regular.ttf}
```

but if I declare

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Path=\@fontdir]{latofont}
```

it does not work.

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "latofont" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.64 ...ont[Ligatures=TeX, Path=\@fontdir]{latofont}

?
```

I guess the option `NFSSFamily` does not work, but you tell me. I'm using MacTex and LuaLatex:

```
$ lualatex -v
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
```

Comment: How is Lato installed? As a system font? In a TeXmf directoty?

Comment: Lato is installed in the system, but I would like to add it from a local dir: `\newcommand*{\fontdir}[1][fonts/]{\def\@fontdir{#1}}
\fontdir`. All the lato ttfs are in the `fonts` dir

Comment: I don't see the point. Wouldn't it be as simple to use the system font?

Comment: Because I want to share it as a class (or I want to share that `.tex` as a project) and not everybody has that font installed. To simplify things that would help a lot.

Comment: I see. Which distribution do you have, on which platform?

Comment: MacTex (Mac Os Sierra) `This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)`

Comment: @Bernard I succeded by defining `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Path=\@fontdir]{Lato-Regular.ttf}` but that's not what I really would like: what I want to do is defining a font family and then use it. I've updated the question with some useful information

Comment: Do you have a GitHub account? If you do, log in and post an issue to the fontspec project there. This sounds like a bug in parsing the code, or perhaps a discrepancy between docs and code.

Comment: @RobtAll Of course I have it, hey, I'm a dev ;) Ok, I'll do it thank you

Comment: You can't use a nfssfont family name in the argument of \setmainfont. Why are you using both \newfontfamily and \setmainfont?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer because I thought that was the correct way: defining a family font and use it. I guess I did not get the right semantic, but defining a family within `setmainfont` I thought that was the right way to get bolds and italics automatically set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. If you want to set your main family to some font simply set it with \setmainfont:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}%[options if needed]

\begin{document}
This is the main (roman) family and it is in Pagella 
\end{document}
```